# Can two computers share one usb-wireless connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have one wireless usb thingy, but I have two desktop computers that I want to go online with.

Is it possible to connect a router to the one computer online, and then hook up the other through this router?

Comment: Question isn't clear: do you want to connect two computers wirelessly to one router? Or directly connect one computer to the router while the other is wireless?

Comment: I want to get both computers online, but I only have one wireless antenna, so I'm wandering if the other computer can share this connection through a router.

Comment: Network shares are drives on one computer that can be accessed on another computer. That's why I removed that tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, so long as the PCs are networked.

The computer with the active connection must be configured for "Internet Sharing", this is easily achievable under Windows, so other operating systems would likely have a reasonable way to also achieve this.

You have several options of connecting the machines to share the internet connection;

1. Go through a router
2. Connect via a simple [switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch)
3. Or you can directly connect the machines via a network [cross over cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable).

Answer (score 0):

- Go into Control Panel, go to Network Connections. You'll probably have to turn off firewall on Windows XP.
- Under Wireless Network Connection » USB LAN card, right click, go to *Properties*.
- Go to *Advanced*, then click *Allow other networks to connect*.
- Uncheck *Allow other network to disable*.
- Hit *OK*, now plug the Ethernet cord into your PC's Ethernet port and the other end into the internet port on your router.
- Hook your other PC to the router